# Push rejected, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my project: https://github.com/NeoXinco/LacerMarket (https://lacermarketcorso.herokuapp.com/)

UPDATE ERROR!

```
git push heroku master

remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'

remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to lacermarketcorso.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/lacermarketcorso.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/lacermarketcorso.git
```

Comment: The error is saying you're using the wrong attribute. Looks like it says `mail` and it is suggesting that you might be wanting `email` instead.

Comment: @Jon this is my project: https://github.com/NeoXinco/LacerMarket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `mail` and not `email`.

Look at your schema (you should include your schema in future posts, instead of a linkto your github)

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

The error above indicates the attribute's name is incorrect.

Comment: @NeoXinco - you just completely changed the question. Please put it back to the original question, mark this answer as correct, and post a new question. That is not good SO etiquette.

Comment: help me now, please

Comment: You're not understanding. I already answered your first question. Then you completely deleted the question that I helped you solve, and put a new question in it's place. Put your original question back, mark my answer as correct, and then start a NEW question in a NEW post. Why would people keep helping you if you're not going to reward their help.

Comment: Thx for help me

Comment: I did this because I have to wait 7 days to post to let me fixed my problem

Comment: IDK what you're talking about. Go to the top of the page, click 'Ask Question', and you can ask another question in a new post.

Comment: It does not make me do it